# Google Docs Redirect 301 error

Tags: http-status-code-301

Google Drive 301 redirect problem in both Internet Explorer 9.0 and Google Chrome.

How to download and recover my documents back?

**Error details:**

```
The webpage at https://docs.google.com/nonceSigner?nonce=7cb3t4occcafo&continue=https://doc-14-bg-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/i5n0sn4aobda0j320f46k73eteiillh3/plshk64l31ed2qevsqk23j88fdobcn2g/1342972800000/16921087564105121353/16921087564105121353/0B4IwZnOWxZeUMUdqOG9iU2dRT3VGMm82aDdWNUV3QQ?e%3Ddownload%26hash%3Dhhjr1n96p6fbnep6l9cudvmg5ec7jr43%26nonce%3Db1573nhruskb0%26user%3D16921087564105121353&hash=f23l5btt5380bvi1fh63om23i6m3t5t4 has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Learn more about this problem.
```

Comment: Try logging into google docs using "incognito mode" in Chrome and turn off all extensions, especially adblocking and privacy ones.

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct document URL and is a public document? Because it returned a HTTP 403 error.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced this in Chrome, IE, and Firefox when trying to download files from Google Drive. Disabling extensions & incognito didn't solve this for me, but I was able to find a workaround by using the Google Drive Desktop app.

https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Based on a hint on cookies on [Google forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/drive/XgwZpN_0gz0), I found a solution:

By allowing Google to set cookies, the problem disappeared for me. Chrome settings > Advanced > Content settings ... > Cookies > Manage exceptions. Allow:

```
https://[*.]google.com:443
https://[*.]googleusercontent.com:443
```

The rule could be more specific but this works. I hope this helps. I had non-default cookie restrictions.